# What is the meaning of the CS and EE abbreviations in these sentences?

Tags: network, terminology, passive-optical-network

They are from Tanenbaum network book:

In CS:

> Bandwidth is the capacity of the media in bits/sec

In EE:

> Bandwidth is the width of the frequency band, measured in Hz

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that CS stands for Computer Science, and EE stands for Electrical Engineering.

What it means is that electrical engineering looks at the physical circuit properties, while computer science looks at the practical application of moving bits. The number of bits can be more, less, or the same as the frequency in Hz, depending on several things, e.g. encoding.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135590/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-cs-and-ee-abbrevia).